# how do i grab first link from out put

Tags: python, webscarab

```
`enter code here`
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.tutorialspoint.com/index.htm"
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(str(link.get('href')))
```

**this is the out put**

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/index.htm https://www.tutorialspoint.com/codingground.htm https://www.tutorialspoint.com/about/about_careers.htm

1. i need to know how do i grab first link

   > https://www.tutorialspoint.com/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

Just index the list.

```
links = soup.find_all('a')[0].get('href')
```

out

```
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/index.htm
```

Comment: its working but when i try to grab more then one its giving me error

Comment: AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-bbecf613d8b0> in <module>
----> 1 links = soup.find_all('a')[0:6].get('href')

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Wierd, worked for me

Answer (score 0):

you can use `find` instead it only gets the first element

`link = soup.find('a').get('href')`

Comment: links = soup.find_all('a')[9].get('href')  its only grabing one link i am unable to grab more then one link

Comment: @masroor_rajput try this `links = [link.get('href') for link in soup.find_all('a')[0:6]]`